# GraphQL field resolver never gets invoked

Tags: graphql

I have these resolvers (it's a console.log dump, so you see the resolvers are really there):

```
resolvers {
  job: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
  jobs: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
  Job: {
    parent: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
    children: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
    companies: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
  },
  company: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
  companies: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
  Company: {
    companies: [AsyncFunction: resolve],
    jobs: [AsyncFunction: resolve]
  }
}
```

Thes are my SDL-type definitions:

```
type Pagination {
  page: Int
  pageSize: Int
  total: Int
  pages: Int
}
input PaginationInput {
  page: Int!
  pageSize: Int!
}

type Job {
  id: Int
  created_at: String
  updated_at: String
  title: String
  parent: Job
  children: JobList
  companies: CompanyList
}

type JobList {
  docs: [Job]
  pagination : Pagination
}

type Company {
  id: Int
  legal_name: String
  created_at: String
  updated_at: String
  jobs: JobList
}

type CompanyList {
  docs: [Company]
  pagination : Pagination
}
```

Running this query

```
{
  job (title: "Senior") {
    title
    companies { 
      docs { legal_name }
      pagination {page pageSize total pages}
    }
    children { 
      docs { title }
      pagination {page pageSize total pages}
    }
  }
}
```

against against the schema renders

```js
{
  "data": {
    "job": {
      "title": "Senior Engineer",
      "companies": null,
      "children": null
    }
  }
}
```

Neither the resolver Job.companies nor Job.children is ever being called i.e. invoked.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: missing repo link

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information here to go on, but what's already visible is that the structure of `resolvers` is highly peculiar. On `resolvers` you both have `Query[fieldName]` fields it seems, like `job` and `jobs`, but you also have entire properties referring to types like `Job` and `Company` (capitalised).

This leads me to believe that your resolver map isn't set up correctly. Remember that resolvers must be on a type. Root resolvers for queries are typically on a `Query` type, and other resolvers on their own respective types. Here it seems like you either are only defining resolvers on the `Query` type or are defining root resolvers on a top-level.

Comment: Thanks for answering despite the scarce information which I provided. I apologize for that. So, if I understand you properly, a resolver like Job.companies will _not_ map to resolve the field companies of the type User.

But where in the query hierarchy would I put the companies resolver in order to resolve the User's companies field?

Comment: I think the problem here is that there is no way one can put resolvers on the type when using SDL. Therefore my desparate to somehow map them on the type via the resolver section. It seem like it's only possible to use top level query resolvers when using sdl. Is that right?

Comment: That's not quite the case luckily! If you take a look at `makeExecutableSchema` (the defacto standard creator for adding resolvers to an SDL schema) you'll see that resolver functions can be added to each individual type as long as you structure your resolvers as recommended there — by `resolvers[typename][fieldname]` https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/generate-schema/

So if you need a resolver for `Job.companies` and `User.companies` they'll need to be added separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's them main mistake, and it found the main hint here:

[Building a GraphQL Server With Node.js](https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/09/06/dive-into-graphql-part-iii-building-a-graphql-server-with-nodejs.html)

*The official express-graphql documentation advises using a rootValue
option instead of adding the resolvers via makeExecutableSchema().
Don't do that - it's a dead end. You won't be able to define type
resolvers that way.*

And - I had to wrap my SDL schema slightly different. So here's a working example code on how it's done. Don't forget to install **express**, **express-graphql**, and **graphql-tools** as dependencies to get the example running:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const GraphQLTools = require('graphql-tools');

const app = express();
const port = 3010;

function findById(id) {
  return (item) => id === item.id;
}

const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    job_id: 1,
    given_name: 'Walt',
    family_name: 'Whitman',
  },
];

const jobs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Poet',
  },
];

const schemaSdl = `
 type Person {
   id: Int
   given_name: String
   family_name: String
   jobs: JobList
 }
 type Job {
   id: Int
   title: String
 }
 type JobList {
   docs: [Job] 
 }
 type Query {
   person(id: Int): Person 
   job(id: Int): Job
   jobs(id: Int): JobList
 }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Person: {
    jobs(parent) {
      return { docs: [jobs.find(findById(parent.job_id))] };
    },
  },
  Query: {
    person(_, { id }) {
      return persons.find(findById(id));
    },
    job(_, { id }) {
      return jobs.find(findById(id));
    },
    jobs(_, { job_id }) {
      return { docs: [jobs.find(findById(job_id))] };
    },
  },
};

const schema = GraphQLTools.makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schemaSdl,
  resolvers,
});

app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send('');
});

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```